# How can I add ' before every line using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Using this command, I can add `"` before every line.

```
awk '{print "\""$0}' file
```

But I want to add `'` instead of `"`, why this command doesn't work?

```
awk '{print "\'"$0}' file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely CANNOT use a single quote inside a single-quote-delimited script as that quote absolutely denotes the end of that script [segment]. The options you have are:

1. Put the script in a file "foo" as `{print "'"$0}` and execute as: `awk -f foo file`, or
2. Use the escape sequence `\047` everywhere you want to print a quote: `awk '{print "\047"$0}' file`, or
3. Save the quote in a variable: `awk -v q=\' '{print q$0}' file`, or
4. Delimit the awk script with double instead of single quotes and escape anything the shell might care about: awk "{print \"'\"\$0}" file
5. Drop out of awk and back to shell just to get the quote: `awk '{print "'\''"$0}' file`

The final list item above is actually 2 separate segments of awk script (`'{print "'` and `'"$0}'`) with a bit of shell in the middle (`\'`) so when the end result is of concatenating those is passed by shell to the `awk` command for execution, you get what you want.

FWIW I'd use "1" if your script is more than a couple of lines, "2" or "3" otherwise with "3" being my personal preference but YMMV. I wouldn't do 4 or 5.

Answer (score 5):

Or use `sed`:

```
sed -e "s/^/\'/" file
```

Answer (score 4):

To have a `'` inside a `'`-delimited string in bash is a bit tricky:

You have to terminate the `'`-string, then have to put the `'` in a quoted way and then re-start the `'`-string:

```
echo 'ab'\''cd'
```

will print

```
ab'cd
```

and, applying this knowledge to your command, you need

```
awk '{print "'\''"$0}' file
```

Same principle: You want

```
{print "'"$0}
```

and have to split at the `'`. So you get 2 parts: `{print "` and `"$0}` which have to be enclosed in `'` and "joined" with a `\'`:

```
'{print "'\''"$0}'
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to just use the ASCII code for `'`:

```
$ awk '{print "\047"$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it would be:

```
$ awk -v c="'" '{print c$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

may be in this way?

```
awk 'sub(/^/,"\x27")'
```

if you like `print`:

```
awk '{print "\x27"$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '$0="'\''"$0'<<XXX
one
two

three
XXX
```

Output:

```
'one
'two
'
'three
```

The character `'` should be escaped for the calling shell as it is processed by it not by `awk`. So at first it has to be closed (2nd `'`), then escaped in the shell (`\'`), then opened again (4th `'`).